# Não está trazendo os registros - Query SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, query

Boa tarde!

Galera, abaixo é a consulta que é para trazer a quantidade de clientes ativos numa coluna e a quantidade de clientes bloqueados em outra coluna, porém, ao executar a query, vem nulo nas duas colunas. OBS: Ao executar as subconsultas separadas, a quantidade vem normalmente.

```
                               --Quantidade de Clientes Bloqueados e Ativos--
SELECT 
BLOQUEADOS. [Quantidade de Clientes Bloqueados],
ATIVOS. [Quantidade de Clientes Ativos]
FROM
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT T.UsuIDCliente) [Quantidade de Clientes Bloqueados]
  FROM Tarefa T
  LEFT JOIN Usuario U
  ON U.UsuID = T.UsuIDCliente
  INNER JOIN ParametroProdutoCliente PPC ON U.UsuID = PPC.UsuID
 WHERE T.TarTitulo = 'Bloquear Cliente - Inadimplente'
   AND T.TarTipID = 572
   AND PPC.ProID = 2
   AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM Tarefa t2
                   WHERE t2.TarTitulo = 'Desbloqueio Cliente'
                     AND t2.TarTipID = 574
                     AND t2.usuidcliente  = t.usuidcliente)) BLOQUEADOS
INNER JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(U.UsuID) [Quantidade de Clientes Ativos]
FROM Usuario U 
INNER JOIN ParametroProdutoCliente PPC ON U.UsuID = PPC.UsuID
LEFT JOIN CurvaABC ABC ON U.CurvaID = ABC.CurvaID
LEFT JOIN Solicitacao S ON U.UsuID = S.UsuIDCliente
LEFT JOIN FRM_3 F3 ON S.SolID = F3.ChamadoID
LEFT JOIN ComplementoColunas CC ON U.UsuID = CC.UsuID AND CC.CompID = 32 AND CC.ColunaID = 12
LEFT JOIN Regioes R ON U.EstadoID = R.EstadoID
LEFT JOIN CRMDetalhesConta DC ON U.UsuID = DC.ContaID
LEFT JOIN CRMRamo RM ON DC.RamoID = RM.RamoID
WHERE U.UsuTipo = 'C'
      AND PPC.ProID = 2
      AND S.SolCaminho = 'Implantação Boavista'
      AND F3.C03 IS NOT NULL
      AND U.EmpLiberada = 1) ATIVOS
ON BLOQUEADOS.[Quantidade de Clientes Bloqueados] = ATIVOS.[Quantidade de Clientes Ativos]
```

Comment: coloca a estrutura das tabelas, modelo ER, qualquer coisa que facilite

Comment: Não precisa, deve ser algum parametro no inner join (eu creio) que não está dando certo. Lembrando que se eu executar as subconsultas, executa normalmente.

Comment: se você precisa de duas colunas, para mostrar apenas quantidade ativo/inativo, porque esse monte de join ? qual a condição que coloca o cliente como ativo ou não ? qual o relacionamento entre as tabelas ? a estrutura serve pra ajudar nessa parte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se as suas duas subcconsultas ja fazem tudo o que você quer, não tem necessidade de fazer JOIN entra as duas.

Alem do mais você está fazendo o join das duas com as colunas de quantidade Bloqueados e Ativos, que no meu ponto de vista dificilmente vai trazer resultados.

Tira o JOIN e troca por uma virgula , 
e tira o ON também.

Tipo:

```
SELECT 
BLOQUEADOS. [Quantidade de Clientes Bloqueados],
ATIVOS. [Quantidade de Clientes Ativos]
FROM
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT T.UsuIDCliente) [Quantidade de Clientes Bloqueados]
  FROM Tarefa T
  LEFT JOIN Usuario U
  ON U.UsuID = T.UsuIDCliente
  INNER JOIN ParametroProdutoCliente PPC ON U.UsuID = PPC.UsuID
 WHERE T.TarTitulo = 'Bloquear Cliente - Inadimplente'
   AND T.TarTipID = 572
   AND PPC.ProID = 2
   AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM Tarefa t2
                   WHERE t2.TarTitulo = 'Desbloqueio Cliente'
                     AND t2.TarTipID = 574
                     AND t2.usuidcliente  = t.usuidcliente)) BLOQUEADOS
,
(SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(U.UsuID) [Quantidade de Clientes Ativos]
FROM Usuario U 
INNER JOIN ParametroProdutoCliente PPC ON U.UsuID = PPC.UsuID
LEFT JOIN CurvaABC ABC ON U.CurvaID = ABC.CurvaID
LEFT JOIN Solicitacao S ON U.UsuID = S.UsuIDCliente
LEFT JOIN FRM_3 F3 ON S.SolID = F3.ChamadoID
LEFT JOIN ComplementoColunas CC ON U.UsuID = CC.UsuID AND CC.CompID = 32 AND CC.ColunaID = 12
LEFT JOIN Regioes R ON U.EstadoID = R.EstadoID
LEFT JOIN CRMDetalhesConta DC ON U.UsuID = DC.ContaID
LEFT JOIN CRMRamo RM ON DC.RamoID = RM.RamoID
WHERE U.UsuTipo = 'C'
      AND PPC.ProID = 2
      AND S.SolCaminho = 'Implantação Boavista'
      AND F3.C03 IS NOT NULL
      AND U.EmpLiberada = 1) ATIVOS
```

Comment: Valeu cara! Era isso mesmo, faltou atenção minha, rsrs. Obrigadão